# Binary Tree Level Sum -

Tags: java, binary-tree

A basic Java sample: Given a binary tree and an integer which is the depth of the target level.
And calculate the sum of the nodes in the target level.

I am adding the value in the functions to the left and right node. Why this solution doesn't work in this case, Can anyone help explain?

Also, when the `travese` function got returned, is it returning to the parent root or more like `break;` in for loop and the flow got stopped?

```
private int sum;

public int levelSum(TreeNode root, int level) {
    sum = 0;
    traverse(root, 1, level, 0);
    return sum;
}

public void traverse(TreeNode root, int depth, int level, int sum) {
    if(root == null) {
        return;
    }

    if(depth == level) {
        return;
    }

    if(root.left != null) {
        traverse(root.left, depth + 1, level, sum + root.left.val);
    }

    if(root.right != null) {
        traverse(root.right, depth + 1, level, sum + root.right.val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Except for the initialization, you never assign to `sum` in the `levelSum` routine.  And `traverse` returns `void`, so you have no way to pass the intermediate `sum` values back up the call stack.  You should probably merge these two routines into a single function that returns `int`.

Comment: I see no `for` loop in your posted code, so I cannot answer your last question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't return the result of summation. You will have to return it.

Then, since you wrote "in the target level", I guess you will have to sum up nodes only in the target level, not nodes before the level.

Try this:

```
public int levelSum(TreeNode root, int level) {
    return traverse(root, 1, level);

}

public void traverse(TreeNode root, int depth, int level){
    int sum = 0;

    if(root == null || depth > level){
        return 0;
    }

    if (depth == level) sum += root.val;

    if(root.left != null) {
        sum += traverse(root.left, depth + 1, level);
    }

    if(root.right != null) {
        sum += traverse(root.right, depth + 1, level);
    }

    return sum;
}
```